# Compilation error in Selenium Webdriver : field package.Classfile.driver is not visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting some sort of compilation error it seems.

I have ‘Common.java’ class inside ‘base’ package. It's a program for starting firefox driver. That, I have kept it in the separate package to make it a one time effort and modularity purpose.

I am calling this class file inside the child class ‘tc_01.java’. This TC_01.jave program is in another package ‘testing’. This TC_01.java file is actually accessing driver from Common.java and start the browser and try some login and logout actions.

My child class TC_01.java is showing me compilation error and Error Message on Mouse Hover is – > “field Common.driver is not visible”.
And, at Console : "**java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The field Common.driver is not visible**"

My Analysis: It seems TC_01.java file is not able to access the 'driver' from 'Common.java'. 
But, I have already written 'extends' keyword for it to inherit the properties.

Please guide me. Thanks

Here is my code:->

```
package base;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class Common {

public FirefoxDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public void BM(){
System.setProperty(“webdriver.gecko.driver”,”D://Rajiv//Selenium//geckodriver.exe”);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(“http://automationpractice.com/index.php”);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@AfterMethod
public void CM(){
driver.close();
}
}

# Pakage – testing; Class – Tc_01.java

package testing;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import base.Common;

public class TC_01 extends Common{
public FirefoxDriver driver;`
@Test
public void TM(){
System.out.println(“Selenium Webdriver Script in Firefox browser using Gecko` `Driver | AutomationPractice.com PAGE LAUNCHED”);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(“search_query_top”)));

try{
    String expectedTitle = “My Store”;
    System.out.println(“ExpectedTile = “+expectedTitle );
    String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(“The actual Title of the Page is = “+actualTitle);
   Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);*/

   System.out.println(“Control has reached here”);
   driver.findElementByClassName(“login”).click(); // field common.driver is not visible
   driver.findElementById(“email”).sendKeys(“*****@yahoo.com”);
   driver.findElementById(“passwd”).sendKeys(“*****”);
   driver.findElementById(“SubmitLogin”).click();

   driver.findElementByClassName(“logout”).click();
   System.out.println(“Sucessfully Logout from the Application”);
   }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the root cause for this issue.
It wasted my 3 days before i asked for help here in this forum.
As i had analysed initially, i had mentioned my driver properties in parent class and was accessing it in Child Class. There was some name mismatch. When it was trying to inherit the properties from parent, it was not accessible and giving me compilation error. I renamed the parent class name to the same name that i was giving while extending in Child Class. And, it worked.
Thanks again to all of you. It is such a wonderful forum to discuss your issue between each other and getting its resolution.